# Visual Studio 2012 - cannot open source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I have problem with visual studio. I added path to header files to CUDA c/C++ -> common -> Additional include directories but i got error "cannot open source file". I can build program without errors but  everything from this headers i have as undefinded. :<

Comment: A path to a library should not go in "Additional include directories".  You should add it as a library or library search path to the project.

Comment: Sorry i had mean header files

Comment: To avoid manually setting up a Visual Studio project for using CUDA and specifying by yourself the paths to include and library directories, you can do the following (this works for Visual Studio 2010, but perhaps for Visual Studio 2012 the procedure is the same): `File->New->Project` and then choose NVIDIA CUDA among the installed templates. This will create a new project ready for use with CUDA code.

Comment: I know that, this is CUDA project. I want add to project openCV headers.

Comment: @john any luck here? facing similar problem...

Comment: I has changed version of visual studio to 2010. It's working much better with cuda than 2012 version.

Comment: I have this problem in VS2017. Project builds and runs, so the include directories are set correctly in the project options for compiler and linker (and PDB files, which I had to jigger for unknown reasons), but IDE can't find include files and therefore can't find symbols (e.g., "Go To Definition.") I tried manually editing the `ItemGroups` in the `vsxproj` file; I tried moving things in the VS project so they mirror the file system. No clues arise; IDE simply refuses to find the include files. I have lots of other projects where this is not a problem.

Comment: I also tried full paths to root in the `include` statements in the C++ files. Again compiler and linker are happy, IDE is not. I tried rebuilding the solution database, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, the code analysis tools, just about anything I could find. No clues at all.

Comment: More data: the debugger steps into the symbols that the IDE cannot see. Right-click and "open document" works even though IDE shows a red squiggly. So everything works well except the "go to definition" and "find all uses" stuff, essential IDE features.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build .cu files in your vs2012 project, you don't need to add additional head in your include. Instead, you can do:

> Right click your project -> Build Costomeizations ... -> Then check
>   whatever cuda version installed on your computer

.
That should add cuda headers and libs to your project.